# how to reduce/remove the left/right hand margin in a grouped UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, margin

How to reduce/remove the left/right hand margin in a grouped UITableView?

Is there a way to do this without defining a custom view, i.e. using a UITableViewController directly?

I'm NOT asking here about the space between cells, it the space to the left & right of cells you see.

EDIT 1: Can I clarify:

- already have a custom UITableViewCell ("@interface AppointCell : UITableViewCell") in my solution
- I think the area to the left and right of these custom UITableViewCell's however are not directly from the cell itself - I say this only as when I put a border around the cell (via it's layer) I can see this - so therefore it seems like the space is from the UITableView itself (not the cells)
- should point out again I'm using GROUPED mode for the table view

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure; just adjust the frame of the UITableView so it's a little wider than its superview and a little to the left (in the negative X direction, in other words) of its left boundary.

Comment: That sounds like the right approach. You might try putting that line in your `-viewWillAppear:animated:`; your view might not have its size set correctly when it first loads, but it definitely should by the time your controller gets notified it’s about to appear.

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work, at least now in iOS 7 and 8. Is there a new approach people are using to accomplish this?

Comment: In iOS 7 and above, grouped table views don’t have margins to the side of their cells. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to create a custom cell view for your table which has padding on the left and right side.

Comment: Ah, well that's an interesting question! I wonder if you can do a resize on the CGRect Frame of the tableview...

Comment: yeah...I might try this out and see how I go

Answer (score 1):

You can also make the cell itself a bit wider. Add this method to your UITableViewCell subclass.

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.origin.x -= marginOffset;
    frame.size.width += 2 * marginOffset;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

I Believe the offset should be 9 points. As a side note: If you set a custom background for the cell, you may also have to set it's selectedBackground.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom cell by extending UITableViewCell. I recommend you to take a look at http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder